# Build only necessary Eclipse RCP plugins for a plugin with Tycho

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, build-process

I'm new in Maven and Tycho and I hope that I'm not ask a silly question. Thanks for reading!!

I'm in a big Eclipse RCP Project with a structure like this:

-plugin 1

|-pom.xml

-plugin 2

|-pom.xml

-plugin 3

|-pom.xml

-plugin 4

|-pom.xml

-product 1

|-pom.xml

-product 2

|-pom.xml

-master

|-pom.xml

In my case the product 1 needs plugin 1 and plugin 2 to be built before and product 2 needs plugin 2, plugin 3 and plugin 4 to be built before.

The master pom.xml-file is the parent of all the plugin and product pom.xml-files. When I run `mvn clean install` on the master pom.xml, all products and plugins are built correctly.

When I run `mvn clean install` on the pom.xml file of product 1, it takes the built .jar-files of plugin 1 and plugin 2. (product 2 analog)

Here is my question. **Is there any possibility to rebuild the necessary plugins for only one product without using already built .jar files and without building "too much" plugins?**

In my case this would mean, that I want run `mvn clean install` on product 1 and it should build also plugin 1 and plugin 2 but not plugin 3-4 and not product 2.

If it helps you, here are sample pom.xml files of my project:

master pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>master</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <tycho.version>0.17.0</tycho.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>../plugin1</module>
    <module>../plugin2</module>
    <module>../plugin3</module>
    <module>../plugin4</module>
    <module>../product1</module>
    <module>../product2</module>
</modules>



<repositories>
    <!-- configure p2 repository to resolve against -->
    <repository>
        <id>Repository1</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>url-to-a-p2-site-on-my-server</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <resolver>p2</resolver>
                <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                <target>
                    <artifact>
                        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myGroupId.target</artifactId>
                        <classifier>targetPlatform</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                </target>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>macosx</os>
                        <ws>cocoa</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
                <ignoreTychoRepositories>false</ignoreTychoRepositories>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    </project>
```

plugin1 pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>master</artifactId>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../master/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>plugin1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>
```

product1 pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>master</artifactId>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../master/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>product1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

<name>product 1 build</name>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <publishArtifacts>true</publishArtifacts>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>materialize-products</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
             
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    </project>
```

All the other plugin and product definitions are analog.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default.

The following should help
[Build single module from multimodule pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612854/build-single-module-from-multimodule-pom)

Readings are
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html